# How to generate results from two different MySQL tables on a single graph

Tags: mysql, swing, netbeans, graph

I want to generate a graph that will have two columns. The one will be for quotes and the other will be for invoices (the two will be compared). The quotes and invoices are in two separate tables called `quotedb` and `invoicedb`. My problem is I can only get it to generate for quotes. I am new to graphs so my question is, how can I manipulate the coding below so that it can display data from both graphs.

here is the coding calling the data from the `quotedb`:

```
//declaring the type of category in the column
String text =cboQIMonth.getSelectedItem().toString();
String empno = cboEmployee.getSelectedItem().toString();
String year = cboQIYear.getSelectedItem().toString();

//connecting the database
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = (Connection)
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/salventri","root","password");
//select statement to retrieve data for the graph
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from quotedb where EXTRACT(MONTH from quote_date)='" + monthnum + "' and EXTRACT(YEAR from quote_date) ='" + year + "' and username=" + empno +"");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
DefaultCategoryDataset ddataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
while (rs.next() ) 
{
    //data to be displayed on the graph 
    ddataset.setValue(rs.getInt("quote_total"),
    rs.getString("quote_number") + " by " + rs.getInt("username"),
    monthnum + " " + cboQIYear.getSelectedItem().toString());                            
}
```

Comment: *"How to generate results from two different MySQL tables on a single graph **in Netbeans IDE?"***  Do it the same way you'd do it in Eclipse (your IDE has nothing to do with the question).

Comment: My experience with Eclipse is the same as with Netbeans so I am unsure on how to do it on either

Comment: @AndrewThompson But how can I get it to read from two different tables? Would I need to create a second `ResultSet` statement?

Comment: The point is, **don't** mention the IDE if it has nothing to do with the problem!

Comment: Okay I have taken the IDE out of the question, now can someone please focus on helping me with an answer instead of whining about my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible combine the two tables in the SQL query so that you get a single ResultSet with all the data you need.

If quote_db contained this:

```
+----------+-------------+
| QUOTE_ID | QUOTE_TOTAL |
+----------+-------------+
| quoteA   |          90 |
| quoteB   |         190 |
| quoteC   |         290 |
| quoteD   |         390 |
+----------+-------------+
```

and invoice_db contained this:

```
+------------+---------------+----------+
| INVOICE_ID | INVOICE_TOTAL | QUOTE_ID |
+------------+---------------+----------+
| invoiceA   |           100 | quoteA   |
| invoiceB   |           200 | quoteB   |
| invoiceC   |           300 | quoteC   |
| invoiceD   |           400 | quoteD   |
+------------+---------------+----------+
```

Then this code:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from INVOICE_DB as iv, QUOTE_DB as qt where qt.QUOTE_ID = iv.QUOTE_ID");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
DefaultCategoryDataset ddataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
while (rs.next()) {
    ddataset.setValue(rs.getInt("invoice_total"),
           "invoice_total",
           rs.getString("invoice_id"));
    ddataset.setValue(rs.getInt("quote_total"),
           "quote_total",
           rs.getString("invoice_id"));
}
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Compare Invoice and Quote", "Invoice ID's", "total", ddataset);
chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.RED);
CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLUE);
ChartFrame frame2 = new ChartFrame("Compare Invoice and Quote", chart);
frame2.setVisible(true);
frame2.setSize(450, 350);
```

Would produce this kind of plot:

[image: Plot of invoice and quote]

If it is not reasonable to join them one could just do two queries:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from INVOICE_DB");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
DefaultCategoryDataset ddataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
while (rs.next()) {
    ddataset.setValue(rs.getInt("invoice_total"),
           "invoice_total",
           rs.getString("invoice_id"));
}
stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from QUOTE_DB");
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
    ddataset.setValue(rs.getInt("quote_total"),
           "quote_total",
           rs.getString("quote_id"));
}
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Compare Invoice and Quote", "Invoice ID's", "total", ddataset);
chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.RED);
CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLUE);
ChartFrame frame2 = new ChartFrame("Compare Invoice and Quote", chart);
frame2.setVisible(true);
frame2.setSize(450, 350);
```

The resulting plot is not as easy to compare invoices and quotes:

[image]

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I am trying to do and it works.